# JQuery SHow Hide clarifcation please

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a following div:

```
<div id="someDIV" style="display: none">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

I've a jquery as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   if (condition==true)
   {
     $("#someDIV").show();
    }
 };
```

For some reason someDiv is not showing up if condition is true. Am I doing something weird here, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren: `)`. With it added before your last semicolon, [your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/V6JFG/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if (condition==true)
   {
     $("#someDIV").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I missed that bracket on my question but not in the code itself. Still not working.